# Systrace by Command Line error

Tags: systrace, android-thread

i am trying to use of systrace. for this, i am reading [official site](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html).

but after run this command on terminal :

```
D:\Software\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace>python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html sched gfx view wm
```

I got these error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "systrace.py", line 48, in <module>
from systrace import run_systrace
File "D:\Software\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\run_systrace.py", line 40, in <module>
from devil import devil_env
File "D:\Software\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\devil_env.py", line 32, in <module>
import dependency_manager  # pylint: disable=import-error
File "D:\Software\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\dependency_manager\dependency_manager\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
from .archive_info import ArchiveInfo
File "D:\Software\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\dependency_manager\dependency_manager\archive_info.py", line 7, in <module>
from dependency_manager import exceptions
File "D:\Software\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\dependency_manager\dependency_manager\exceptions.py", line 5, in <module>
from py_utils import cloud_storage
File "D:\Software\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\common\py_utils\py_utils\cloud_storage.py", line 20, in <module>
from py_utils import lock
File "D:\Software\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\common\py_utils\py_utils\lock.py", line 18, in <module>
import win32con    # pylint: disable=import-error
ImportError: No module named win32con
```

my python version:

```
D:\Software\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace>python --version
Python 2.7.13

D:\Software\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\systrace>
```

I have added python **PATH** to ** system ENVIRONMENT** . my main goal of use Systrace by command is using of **Tracing Application Code**. I put:

```
Trace.beginSection("MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder");
```

and

```
Trace.endSection();
```

to my code and i want to see this output as a trace to systrace by  **-a or --app= options**.

GUI systrace is ok on **google chrome** and work excellent in this browser.

Answer (score 3):

python doesn't come with pywin32 library. you just need to download pywin32 version according to your system from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20221/ and install it. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

For me, running

`pip install pypiwin32`

fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

My error stacktrace

```
 C:\Users\hhh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace>python
 systrace.py --time=10 -o my_systrace.html Traceback (most recent call
 last):   File "systrace.py", line 48, in <module>
     from systrace import run_systrace   File "C:\Users\hhh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\run_systrace.py",
 line 43, in <module>
     from systrace import systrace_runner   File "C:\Users\hhh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\systrace_runner.py",
 line 11, in <module>
     from systrace import output_generator   File "C:\Users\hhh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\output_generator.py",
 line 15, in <module>
     from tracing.trace_data import trace_data   File "C:\Users\hhh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\tracing\tracing\trace_data\trace_data.py",
 line 17, in <module>
     import six ImportError: No module named six
```

I solved the problem:

`pip install six`

**summary**
find ImportError what, use pip install it

Answer (score 0):

In Windows10 when running through the command line, I got the same errors!

But if run systrace from Android Device Monitor all work fine!

To do this:

- run  Android Device Monitor
- click DDMS icon
- in the "Devices" tab select your device
- click "Capture system wide trace using Android systrace" (Near the icon " Screen Capture")

I use Android Device Monitor Version: 25.2.2

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Python 3.8, I just switched to 2.7.